# no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Block conforms to Supplier<T>

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I was just coding from a course,  when there was this error:

`no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that Block conforms to Supplier<T>`

I don't know what it is, but here is my code:

```java
package com.berriz44.breloaded.block;

import com.berriz44.breloaded.util.Registration;
import net.minecraft.world.item.BlockItem;
import net.minecraft.world.item.CreativeModeTab;
import net.minecraft.world.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.SoundType;
import net.minecraft.world.level.block.state.BlockBehaviour;
import net.minecraft.world.level.material.Material;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.RegistryObject;

import java.util.function.Supplier;

public class ModBlocks {

    public static RegistryObject<Block> SMOOTH_BRICK = register("smooth_brick", new Block(BlockBehaviour.Properties.of(Material.STONE).sound(SoundType.STONE).strength(2f,6f)));

    private static <T extends Block>RegistryObject<T> register(String name, Supplier<T> block) {
        RegistryObject<T> toReturn = Registration.BLOCKS.register(name, block);
        Registration.ITEMS.register(name, () -> new BlockItem(toReturn.get(), new Item.Properties().tab(CreativeModeTab.TAB_BUILDING_BLOCKS)));
        return toReturn;
    }

}
```

**Send help.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method `register` takes a `Supplier<Block>`, not a `Block`.

You are trying to pass it a `Block` here instead of a `Supplier<Block>`:

```
public static RegistryObject<Block> SMOOTH_BRICK = register("smooth_brick",
    new Block(BlockBehaviour.Properties.of(Material.STONE).sound(SoundType.STONE).strength(2f,6f)));
```

You can implement `Supplier<Block>` with a lambda expression:

```
public static RegistryObject<Block> SMOOTH_BRICK = register("smooth_brick",
    () -> new Block(BlockBehaviour.Properties.of(Material.STONE).sound(SoundType.STONE).strength(2f,6f)));
```

Comment: thanks a lot! once i finally reach my fat32 drive on an ubuntu system, i will be ready to go :D